# Disable certain checkboxes from Jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

So I have a Checkbox Tree created with JsTree. What I want to do is to set all the checkboxes initially to disabled and then I have an Array that contains the ids of the li tags. by browsing the table I should enable the checkboxes that belong to the tag with the specific id. When checked the Tree should respect the same orders as the default one (when parent checked enabled children should be checked as well ... etc). How can I proceed ? Thanks in advance.
PS: The JsTree Plugin is wonderful. However it lacks a lot of documentation.

Comment: You can use the normal JStree events and bog standard JQuery / Javascript for this. Nothing special is required of JSTree. Basically, do something in the JSTree load function to loop all checkboxes and disable them. Then in the JSTree selection function, enable what you need.

Comment: can you create this html and suggest a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The problem is I don't have input of checkbox type so I can disable them...

Comment: @webnoob I would be really grateful if you give us an example with Fiddle :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should overwrite default behaviour of `check_node` and `uncheck_node` functions, and create own disabled node type.

The code:

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'plugins' : ['themes', 'html_data', 'checkbox', 'types'],
    'checkbox' : {
      'two_state' : true // Nessesary to disable default checking childrens
    },
    "types" : {
      "types": {
        "disabled" : { // Defining new type 'disabled'
          "check_node" : false, 
          "uncheck_node" : false 
        }, 
        "default" : { // Override default functionality
          "check_node" : function (node) {
            $(node).children('ul').children('li').children('a').children('.jstree-checkbox').click();
            return true;
          },
          "uncheck_node" : function (node) {
            $(node).children('ul').children('li').children('a').children('.jstree-checkbox').click();
            return true;
          }
        } 
      }
    }
});
```

Now to disable a node, add attribute `rel="disabled"` to their `li` tag.

[Here is an example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6mtfL/1/)